# Display message in pop up instead of redirecting to another page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, popup

once registered user click on button in [view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-7.html) we are creating new product and displaying that information in pop up as below

[image]

button code : [ full code : https://pastebin.com/da60SSWH ]

```
    <button  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo 

Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();" 

  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">save design</button>
```

image url script [ full code : https://pastebin.com/19K43TyR ]

```
saveImageDefaultUrl   : '<?php echo Mage::helper('aitcg')-

>getSecureUnsecureUrl(Mage::getUrl('aitcg/ajax/createImageDefault',array('id' =>

 Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()))); ?>',
```

but if guest click on same button, its creating new product , but its **redirecting to another page , but we want to display that message in pop up**....   [ controllers : https://pastebin.com/9wsgufJX ]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will require to add jQuery for this. Try adding below jquery code in your login popup "Login into your Account 4"

Add below code after this line,

```
var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form', true);

jQuery("#ajaxlogin-login-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ajaxLoginForm.validator.validate()) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').attr('action'),
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('There is some error saving your design.');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: check updated code, you need to add the code after line `var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form', true);`

Comment: sorry, in a hurry to reply you, i didt observed , updated as you suggested, https://pastebin.com/XVacqNhg

Comment: Please use `ajaxLoginForm`  instead of `myform`  check updated code

Comment: updated ajaxLoginForm code

Comment: The code is not working because you need to add `id` to your form. `<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>" id="ajaxlogin-login-form">`

Comment: sorry for that, updated code , i am getting result as `There is some error saving your design`  as here : http://prnt.sc/ev1v3k

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56910/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-baby-in-magento).